# How to update a field type in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

The ElasticSearch documents just aren't clear on how to do this.

I indexed some tweets, and one of the fields, created_at, indexed as a string instead of a date. I can't find how to reindex with this change via a curl call. If reindexing is a complicated process, then I would much rather just delete what's there and start over. But, I can't find how to specify the field types either!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to define a mapping using [Put Mapping AP](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-put-mapping/)I.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_doc/_mapping' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '
{
    "_doc" : {
        "properties" : {
            "message" : {"type" : "text", "store" : true}
        }
    }
}
'
```

A date can be defined as follow:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_doc/_mapping' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '
{
    "_doc" : {
        "properties" : {
            "user" : {"type" : "keyword", "null_value" : "na"},
            "message" : {"type" : "text"},
            "postDate" : {"type" : "date"},
            "priority" : {"type" : "integer"},
            "rank" : {"type" : "float"}
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: @dadoonet Any way to change the "message" filed type change from string to "long".Merge failed with failures {[mapper [message] of different type, current_type [string]

Comment: @dibish No. You need to reindex.

Comment: "error": "MergeMappingException[Merge failed with failures {[mapper [event-time] of different type, current_type [string], merged_type [date]]}]",

Comment: @Tyguy7 event-time type was earlier string and then you tried to change it to date. Changing the type just like that is not allowed because it will interfere with the indexing of the document containing this field. You will need to delete this type and recreate its mapping from start.

Answer (score 9):

You also need to specify format not just type if you are inserting a mysql timestamp then you should just add a format to it like this.

```
"properties": {
    "updated_at": {
         "type": "date",
         "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
     }
 }
```

If we consider your example then it should be like

```
"tweet" : {
    "properties" : {
        "user" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
        "message" : {"type" : "string", "null_value" : "na"},
        "postDate" : {"type" : "date" , "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" },
        "priority" : {"type" : "integer"},
        "rank" : {"type" : "float"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Why this is throwing an error then 
PUT filebeat-2018.10.22
{
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "system": { "type": "float" },
                "idle":  { "type": "float"}
                
            }
        }
    }
}

resource_already_exists_exception

Answer (score 9):

New version of Elasticsearch wont support field type changing, But we can achive this by reindexing. You can follow the below steps to achive the reindeing of an index and change the type in Elasticsearch.

**Create new index**

```
PUT project_new
```

Update the mapping with new field type mapping

```
PUT project_new/_mapping/_doc
{
    "properties": {
        "created_by": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "created_date": {
            "type": "date"
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "text"
        }
}
}
```

Reindex the new index with old one ie data migrations

```
POST _reindex
{
    "source": {
        "index": "project"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "project_new",
        "version_type": "external"
    }
}
```

Change the alias of newly created index to point to old index name

```
POST _aliases
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "add": {
                "index": "project_new",
                "alias": "project"
            }
        },
        {
            "remove_index": {
                "index": "project"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now you will be able to view the updated type in your existing index.

Tested and working in **Eleasticsearch Version 6.4.3**

Answer (score 2):

Updating a field type in existing index:

```
PUT test-index/_doc/_mapping
{
    "doc" : {
        "properties" : {
            "testDateField" : {"type" : "date"}
        }
    }
}
```

Adding a field with specific type in existing index:

```
PUT test-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "testDateField" : {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```