# How to specify integer type for csv-river generated type in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Seems I'm way out of my league here and hope that someone frome the Elasticsearch community can tune in and pinpoint me to my error.

I wanted to try out Kibana + Elastic search for fiddling with some COUNTER3-compliant stats we have and for this needed to import CSV files.

I choose the [CSV River plugin](https://github.com/AgileWorksOrg/elasticsearch-river-csv) to import the csv files.
The river-csv was configured with following PUT request to  http://localhost:9200/_river/test_csv_river/_meta

```
{
  "type": "csv",
  "csv_file": {
    "folder": "C:\\localdata\\UsageStats\\COUNTER3",
    "first_line_is_header": "true"
  }
}
```

This works fine but it turns out that the number fields are imported as strings, not numbers. Confirmed by checking on the indexes type mapping : http://localhost:9200/test_csv_river/csv_type/_mapping

```
{
    test_csv_river: {
        mappings: {
            csv_type: {
                properties: {
                    ft_total: {
                        type: "string"
                    },
                    .....
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This related SO question made me believe that I can change the types field properties ***AFTER*** I have created the index: [How to update a field type in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290636/how-to-update-a-field-type-in-elasticsearch)?

But when I made the following PUT Request I get an error 
***{"error":"MergeMappingException[Merge failed with failures {[mapper [ft_total] of different type, current_type [string], merged_type [integer]]}]","status":400}***

http://localhost:9200/test_csv_river/csv_type/_mapping

```
{
    "csv_type" : {
        "properties" : {
            "ft_total" : {"type" : "integer", "store" : "yes"}
        }
    }
}
```

Is there no way to update that type from string > integer?

Alternatively, is there any way I can make sure the index is created with a specific field ***predefined*** as "type" : "integer" when using the CSV river plugin ?

Comment: I have the same problem , did you resolve this ?