# How to enforce index property to be numeric (or float)?

Tags: django, python-3.x, elasticsearch

According to this [How to update a field type in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290636/how-to-update-a-field-type-in-elasticsearch), I have added [Put Mapping AP](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-put-mapping/). However Kibana, I get property as unknown (See screenshot below). In rank field, there's numeric values or 0.

```
{
"tweet" : {
    "properties" : {
        "user" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
        "message" : {"type" : "string", "null_value" : "na"},
        "postDate" : {"type" : "date"},
        "priority" : {"type" : "integer"},
        "rank" : {"type" : "float"}
    }
}
}
```

[image: Kibana screen - you see rank as (?) unknown type]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh Field list, fix the problem

Any fields added later need refresh. To do so:

1. Go to Kiabana
2. Go to Management and select Index.
3. Click on Refresh Field List.

[image]